# Use postgesql's function that takes an argument of array type in spring-data repository method

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm using a `@Modifying` spring-data repository update query that utilizes Postgresql function `jsonb_set(...)` to be able to update specific nodes on the stored JSON value. The repository method looks like the following

```
@Query(value = "UPDATE AutosavedEntityDAO ae " +
            "SET ae.json = jsonb_set(ae.json, '{myJsonNode}', to_jsonb(:json)) " +
            "WHERE ae.id=:id")
@Modifying
void updateNode(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("json") String json);
```

And that is working quite well until I try to change the repository method's signature and make the `path` argument configurable, e.g.:

```
@Query(value = "UPDATE AutosavedEntityDAO ae " +
            "SET ae.json = jsonb_set(ae.json, :path, to_jsonb(:json)) " +
            "WHERE ae.id=:id")
@Modifying
void updateNode(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("path") String[] path, @Param("json") String json);
```

According to postresql docs the `jsonb_set` signature is the following 
`jsonb_set(target jsonb, path text[], new_value jsonb [, create_missing boolean])`. The second argument to the function is of postgesql's `text[]` and it looks like that `@Param("path") String[] path` cannot be mapped to a `text[]`

Is there a way to provide a dynamic value for `path` argument via spring repository method? Any known workarounds?